# Invertible Matrices with an Operation

Tags: matrices

I've been working a tad on matrices, and I had a question about invertible matrices that was confusing. How would I go about solving the following problem -

Let $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ be invertible matrices such that
$\mathbf{A} \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} \text{ and } \mathbf{B} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}.$ Calculate $(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B})^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}.$

I've tried solving for the individual matrices, but I can't find them. Is there a property of inverse matrices that I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that $$B\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$$ by substituting in the other equation we obtain $$A\begin{pmatrix} 2\\-1 \end{pmatrix} = AB\begin{pmatrix} 1\\3 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} $$therefore $$(AB)^{-1}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ and $B$ are both invertible, then $AB$ is invertible and $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$.

With that property you should solve it easily...

Answer (score 0):

$(AB)^{-1}(1,2)=B^{-1}A^{-1}(1,2)=B^{-1}(2,-1)=(1,3)$.